# How to run scala class on IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have installed scala plugin in IDEA, set scala SDK and created a scala module.But I can only find "Compile" and "Run Scala Console" option.How can I run scala class like java?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change class `Hello` to object such as described in : 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-and-running-your-scala-application.html

Answer (score 0):

I has similar issue, i replaced `main` method in class to object `Main extends App {}` analogue. After idea restart i could use both variant. it's trouble of intellij.

Answer (score -1):

It is a mistake! We should create a object which contains main to run scala application:

```
class Hello {

}

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
```